# Delete "sizes" attribute - wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

i'm just trying display image on my wordpress page from admin panel... and it works, but it generates me a lot of useless attributes... now its looks like this:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-50" src="uploads/2016/02/moves.jpg" 
alt="moves" srcset="uploads/2016/02/moves-300x191.jpg 300w,
uploads/2016/02/moves.jpg 700w" sizes="(max-width: 700px) 100vw, 700px">
```

i need only this:

```
<img class="wp-image-50" src="uploads/2016/02/moves.jpg alt="moves">
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `useless attributes` in who's eyes? The `sizes attribute` is part of the HTML5 ref spec. It provides a way - amongst other things - to change the size of an image based on a media query, saving you the need to generate these rules in your CSS file (which have become just absolutely huge these days). What is your real purpose and intent here? Why does this attribute bother you? Are you wanting to change the attribute values? This is **only** for the admin panel, mind you.

Comment: I want to pass my static html to WordPress, these attributes make my css is overwritten. I do not like that these attributes are there, I would have it in my css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `wp_get_attachment_image_src` example

```
 $src= wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 720,405 ), false, '' );
```

in HTML

```
<img src="<?php echo $src[0];?>" class="wp-image-50" alt="move" >
```

Comment: Could you explain me, where should i add the first lane? To my functions.php or where?

Comment: Add in your loop, example:  `while(have_posts()): the_post();  $src= wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), array( 720,405 ), false, '' ); endwhile;`